# Getting the LocalStorageProxy working with a TreeStore

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, local-storage, extjs

Hullo there,

I am building a Sencha Touch iPhone app that utilises a TreeStore which works nicely with a NestedList but I've hit a wall.

It needs a way to read data in a static store (the TreeStore), load it into localStorage so it's writable and then save some user preferences. I've figured out that the localStorageProxy is most likely what I need (I was relieved to discover I didn't have to serialise and deserialise the JSON store manually!) but after reading the documentation on it and trying and failing a few things I'm at a loss.

As it stands, it generates the localStorage… storage but it's empty, this I guess is because I haven't loaded anything into it but on doing `app.stores.event_store.load();` the screen is blank and Console shows that the localStorage is empty with no errors.

My model:

```
Ext.regModel('Events', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'text',      type: 'string'},
        {name: 'info',      type: 'string'},
        {name: 'attend',    type: 'boolean', defaultValue: 'false'}
    ]   
});
```

My store:

```
app.stores.event_store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'Events',
    root: data,
    storeId: 'eventStoreId',
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'eventsAttending',
        url: 'store.js',
        reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

app.stores.event_store.load();
```

It probably stems from a lack of a fundamental understanding of how these models and stores interact but if anyone could help, good karma will be sent your way.

The full application can be found at [it's GitHub repo](http://github.com/fetimo/Schedlr).

-fetimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TreeStore expects hierarchical data

```
var data= { 
    text: 'Groceries',
    items: [{
        text: 'Drinks',
        items: [{
            text: 'Water',
            items: [{
                text: 'Sparkling',
                leaf: true
            },{
                text: 'Still',
                leaf: true
            }]
        },{
            text: 'Coffee',
            leaf: true
        }]
    }] 
}
```

But the LocalStorageProxy is unable to match the model for this data structure.

I would use an AJAX request to load the "store.js" file using the localStorage directly to "store" the data blob.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'store.js',
    success: function(response, opts) {
       localStorage.StoreJSBlob = response.responseText;
    }
});
```

then your store will look something like this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'Events',
    root: localStore.StoreJSBlob,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

You just have to chain the events together correctly, as the async calls could trip you up

Comment: I feared this was the only way to go. What a shame. And I spent to much time getting the localStorage store working for my basic list!